# Вы(,) являясь мокрой(,) домой пришли?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Суть вопроса не в том, пришёл ли человек, а в том, мокрым ли он, когда пришёл, был, так что, очевидно, нельзя изъять этот оборот, срода деепричастный.

`Вы домой пришли(,) являясь мокрой?`

`Являясь мокрой(,) Вы домой пришли?`

`Вы(,) являясь мокрой(,) домой пришли?`

Comment: Лео, ну невозможно уже, простите. Зачем вам это "являясь"? Никто так не скажет, кроме вас, наверное. "Вы домой пришли мокрой?" – всё, больше ничего не надо, просто, понятно и по-русски.

Comment: На третий день пришёл домой — был пьян как стелька я. Гляжу — чужая пара брюк, где быть должна моя. ©

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что можно обойтись без запятых:

***Вы домой пришли являясь мокрой?***

***Являясь мокрой Вы домой пришли?***

***Вы являясь мокрой домой пришли?*** — тесная связь со сказуемым: важно не просто то, что кто-то пришел домой, — важно, что она пришла мокрой.

Comment: Грамматику надо изучать на грамматически правильно построенных предложениях! Is it really necessary to explain this?

Comment: @Sharon А что не так?

Comment: Александр объяснил, что не так.  Что же мне повторяться?

Comment: Я всë же не понимаю, что здесь некорректного. Вроде не деепричастный оборот, относящийся к «мне понравилось». А слово «являясь» что, нельзя оставить, если вы об этом?

Comment: Я о том, что нельзя изучать грамматику на неестественно построенном предложении.  Это совершенно бесполезное занятие:  вы не получите никаких знаний, а неправильный вывод можете сделать.

Comment: @Sharon А что неестественного-то?

Comment: Нельзя прийти и являться. Или можно? Тогда поведайте нам, как вы это себе представляете.

Comment: @Sharon А _будучи_ можно?

Comment: Тоже нельзя. С глаголом прийти оно не сочетается. К тому же у  этого слова книжный стиль и ограниченная область применения. И на этом заканчиваем дискуссию.

Comment: @Sharon Не знал. Но Леополбду, скорее всего, пофиг на это.